# Can't find my downloaded file in cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I'm working on visual studio 2013 apache cordova app . I want to download file from remote server into my device . It successfully downloaded in path `"file:///data/data/io.cordova.myapp/files/Download-Button1.png", but i can't find the file . I want to download it in download folder . here is my code :

```
    $("#SaveFiles").click(function () {

        var pathToFile = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "Download-Button1.png";

        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var uri = encodeURI("http://www.techaudible.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Download-Button1.png");

        fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
             pathToFile,
            function (entry) {
                alert("download complete: " + pathToFile);
            },
            function (error) {
                alert("download error source " + error.source);
            },
            false,
            {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                }
            }
        );

    });
```